# Redux: Two components load same resource, show loader in only one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's say I have components `FooList` and `DoThingWithFooModal`. Both are mountend and both can request `foos` from an api.

The state for `foos` looks like this:

```
foos: {
  state: 'LOADING' | 'OK' | 'ERROR',
  items: [foo1, foo2, ...],
}
```

When `foos.state` is `'LOADING'`, both components show a `<Loader />`.

**What I want to achieve, is to show the `Loader` *only* in the component that *requested* `foos` - either the modal, or the list.**

(In my specific case, the list is hidden behind the modal so it's not really an issue. However, I'd like to find good solutions to this problem.)

One thing I came up with, is to store more context in `foos` state:

```
foos: {
  ...foos,
  requestedBy: 'DoThingWithFooModal',
}
```

Unfortunately, this adds more complexity (1. introduce constants for possible requestees, 2. decide whether to show loader) and just doesn't look good.

What other solutions are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want some state to be local, make it local!

```
this.setState({ isFetching: true })
this.props.fetchFoo().then(() => {
  this.setState({ isFetching: false })
})
```

Don’t put something into Redux if you only ever want to use it inside a single component.
If you later need this state elsewhere, you can use the global state for it, or mix both approaches.